# How to convert $r = 2s\cos (\theta+t)$ into Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

How would I convert $r = 2s\cos (\theta+t)$ into Cartesian coordinates? I believe $r$ currently is in polar coordinates. However, polar coordinates are in form $(r,\theta)$ and the equation given is not in that form. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The given equation is in the correct form.

$$\begin{align}
r & =2s\cos(\theta+t)\\
r & =2s(\cos\theta\cos t-\sin\theta\sin t)\\
r & =2s\left(\frac xr\cos t-\frac yr\sin t\right)\\
r^2 & =2s(x\cos t-y\sin t)
\end{align}$$

Comment: I am trying to find: real numbers $s$ and $t$ such that $\Gamma$ is the graph of $r = 2s \cos (\theta + t)$. $\Gamma$ passes through the origin, and is a circle. How would you advise that I apply the Cartesian equation to the problem?